# What happens to the applied sales rules when items are cancelled?

Tags: sales-order, shopping-cart-price-rules

I'm not sure magento supports the partial cancellation(cancel only subset of items from order)

Below is my guess how magento works with this issue, but need confirmation.

It seems one can achieve the `partial cancellation` by creating `partial invoice` (dropping the items that needs to be cancelled)

When creating a invoice, magento re-inspect rules that holds (without the dropped items) and recalculate the total.

magento doesn't have a function where it `removes sales rules already applied` it only re-inspect the rules whenever it goes from order -> invoice.

(otherwise how can one ensure that cancellation doesn't affect the sales rules in some unwanted way?) <= this is my question

Answer (score 0):

I've read magento 1.9 source and it doesn't seem to support partial item cancellation (from order or invoice)

`It seems one can achieve the partial cancellation by creating partial invoice (dropping the items that needs to be cancelled)`

This is true but magento doesn't validate rules after order has been created.

So you are on your own if you want to cancel items partially where items can have applied rules.